# Why moment() does not increment seconds?

Tags: node.js

I am new to Node JS and sorry if my question is really simple

Tried the following code on Windows 10 and Ubuntu and I don't get the 'seconds' incremented in the output

**Code**

```
var moment = require('moment')

for(let step = 0; step < 5; step++ ) {
    console.log(moment().format('DDMMYYYY-hhmmss'));
}
```

**Output**

```
C:\Users\sathish>node form.js
23122022-045601
23122022-045601
23122022-045601
23122022-045601
23122022-045601
```

**Expected output**

```
23122022-045601
23122022-045602
23122022-045603
23122022-045604
23122022-045605
```

Kindly let me know what am I missing

Comment: You are missing that a loop with this code runs so fast that a second has not passed between your calls to `moment()`.

Comment: Because that loop runs within a few milliseconds ....

Comment: Yes.  I am able to see the change in seconds if I execute the loop for 10000 times.  Thanks to both of you